# MS Access Queries in vba excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

```
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")


objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\" & sUser & "\Downloads\ICO\" & DB & ".mdb"

objAccess.DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].TYPE AS Type, [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].[HOLDING CO] AS [HOLDING CO], [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].CODE AS CODE, [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].ST AS ST, [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].STLVL AS STLVL, [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].STCMP AS STCMP, [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].JUR AS JUR, Sum([Total-7yr_27Mar2017].[OR LS MOU]) AS OR_LS_MOU, Sum([Total-7yr_27Mar2017].[UP LS MOU]) AS UP_LS_MOU, Sum([Total-7yr_27Mar2017].[TOT USG EXP]) AS UP_USG_EXP INTO 7yr_Total_Varients
 FROM [Total-7yr_27Mar2017]
 GROUP BY [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].TYPE, [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].[HOLDING CO], [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].CODE, [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].ST, [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].STLVL, [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].STCMP, [Total-7yr_27Mar2017].JUR"
```

`Docmd.RunSQL` is working sometimes and giving error as Docmd.RunSQL is not reliable for select queries. So I tried with Database.execute and adodb.connection adobd.recordset.it throwing error that 7yr_Total_Varients already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your SQL to change the query from a *create table query* to an *append query*.